# Rewriting urls of templates

Tags: templates, url, groups

I have some templates in a group called 'client area'

they include

```
client_area
  - profile
  - editprofile
```

so these resolve to

```
client_area/profile
client_area/editprofile
```

I want edit profile to resolve to

```
client_area/profile/editprofile
```

without having to create a sub group of proifile. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by using a conditional within the client_area/profile template.

```
{if segment_3=='editprofile'}
    Embed your edit profile template
{if:else}
    Show the user's profile
{/if}
```

Comment: You might be better off using Switchee instead of the built in conditionals as this will then only parse the content of the matching condition rather than everything as the if:else will do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest 2.8.x version of EE? If so, you should be able to use the new native Template Routing functionality to achieve this. If you're on an older version you can use the Resource Router add-on (https://github.com/rsanchez/resource_router) to do the same thing and save yourself embed overhead.

Comment: I am using 2.7.3

Comment: So then you'd need to give the addon a shot if you wanted to try the url routing.